# Найти число, сумма квадратов делителей которого является квадратом целого числа

Tags: python

Нужно найти все такие числа в интервале от 1 до 250.

**РЕШЕНИЕ РАБОТАЕТ, просто нужно оптимизировать**

codewars не принимает из за времени выполнения(

```
import time

t1 = time.time()
def list_squared(m, n):
    need_numbers = []
    for i in range(m, n):
        divisors = [elem*elem for elem in range(1, (i+1)/elem) if i % elem == 0 ]       
        da = sum(divisors)**(0.5)
        if da.is_integer():
            need_numbers.append([i, sum(divisors)]) 
    return need_numbers



print(list_squared(1, 250))
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

Comment: Как же функция работает, когда она не работает? `name 'elem' is not defined` - в списке делителей `range(1, (i+1)/elem)` используется переменная `elem` которая ещё не определена

Comment: да, sry за это. А вопрос остается тот же))) Как мне его оптимизировать?

Comment: добавил оптимизированное решение. Для интервала 1-10000 ищет подходящие числа за 150 миллисекунд

Answer (score 3):

Уберите деление на `elem` в списке, оставьте `range(1, (i+1))`, и тогда всё заработает.

Время счёта 1.5 миллисекунды. Мне кажется, оптимизировать нет необходимости.

```
import time

t1 = time.time()
def list_squared(m, n):
    need_numbers = []
    for i in range(m, n):
        divisors = [elem*elem for elem in range(1, (i+1)) if i % elem == 0 ]       
        da = sum(divisors)**(0.5)
        if da.is_integer():
            need_numbers.append([i, sum(divisors)]) 
    return need_numbers



print(list_squared(1, 250))
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

Вывод:

```
[[1, 1], [42, 2500], [246, 84100]]
0.0015308856964111328
```

## UPDATE

Топик-стартер попросил оптимизированное решение. Ок.

Оптимизированное решение использует тот факт, что все делители числа `n` состоят из тех же простых чисел, что делят само число `n`. Например, делители числа 300 1, 5, 25, 3, 15, 75, 2, 10, 50, 6, 30, 150, 4, 20, 100, 12, 60, 300 сами делятся только на 2,3,5. Ну и единица, понятное дело.

Поэтому для ускорения счёта нужно разложить число `n` на простые множители, найти для каждого множителя с какой степенью оно делит число `n` и построить все комбинации произведений простых сомножителей.

**Пример**
`300 = 2**2 * 3 * 5**2`
Значит, делителями будут: `1, 2**1, 2**2, 3, 2*3, 2**2 * 3, 5, 2**2 * 5, 2*3*5, 2**2 *3*5, 5**2, 2**2 * 5**2, 2*3*5**2, 2**2 *3*5**2, 3*5, 3 * 5**2`.

```
import math

# Список простых чисел, меньших 1000
primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23,
29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67,
71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109,
113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167,
173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227,
229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277,
281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347,
349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401,
409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461,
463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523,
541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599,
601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653,
659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727,
733, 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797,
809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859,
863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937,
941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]

def find_prime_divisor(n):
    "Функция наименьший простой делитель числа n"
    lim = math.floor(math.sqrt(n+1))
    # Сначала проверим простые из списка
    for p in primes:
        if p > lim:
            # p*p > n -- дальше перебирать бессмысленно, n не делится на такое большое p
            break
        if n%p == 0:
            # Нашли делитель
            return p
    if p > lim:
        # n меньше миллиона, и не делится ни на одно простое из списка
        # следовательно, n - простое
        return n
    # n больше миллиона. Ищем его делители лобовым перебором. 
    for m in range(p, n,2):
        if n%m == 0:
            return m
    # делители не найдены. n - простое число
    return n

def get_divisor_degree(m,n):
    """Функция возвращает максимальную степень d числа m, при которой m**d делит n
    Возвращается пара (d, n/m**d)
    """
    deg = 0
    while n%m == 0:
        deg += 1
        n //= m
    return deg, n

def factorize(n):
    """Функция раскладывает n на простые множители.
    Возвращается набор пар (простой_делитель, степень_делителя) в виде словаря."""
    factors = {}
    while n > 1:
        p = find_prime_divisor(n)
        deg, n = get_divisor_degree(p,n)
        factors[p] = deg
    return factors

def gen_divisors(factors):
    """Генератор делителей из списка пар (простой_делитель, степень_делителя)"""
    if isinstance(factors, dict):
        factors = list(factors.items())
    if len(factors) == 0:
        # Пустой список - вовзращаем 1
        yield 1
    else:
        # вынимает первый делитель из списка
        p, deg = factors[0]
        p_m = 1
        for _ in range(deg+1):
            # генерируем делители из остальных простых делителей 
            # и умножаем их последовательно на степени p
            for div in gen_divisors(factors[1:]):
                yield p_m*div
            p_m *= p
​
def list_divisors(n):
    '''Функция возвращает список всех делителей числа n'''
    return list(gen_divisors(factorize(n)))
​
def is_square(n):
    "Функция возвращает True, если целое число n является квадратом другого целого числа."
    root = math.floor(math.sqrt(n+1))
    return  root*root == n
is_square(625), is_square(101)
(True, False)

def check_number(n):
    "Функция возвращает True если число подходит под условие задачи, и сумму квадратов делителей"
    divs = list_divisors(n)
    divs_square = sum(map(lambda x:x*x, divs))
    return is_square(divs_square), divs_square

def run(iterable):
    "Функция проверяет каждое число из итератора и генерирует пары (число, сумма квадратов делителей) для подходящих" 
    for n in iterable:
        good, divs_square = check_number(n)
        if good:
            yield n, divs_square

print(list(run(range(1, 10000))))
```

Вывод:

```
[(1, 1), (42, 2500), (246, 84100), (287, 84100), (728, 722500), (1434, 2856100), (1673, 2856100), (1880, 4884100), (4264, 24304900), (6237, 45024100), (9799, 96079204), (9855, 113635600)]
```

Время работы 130-150 миллисекунд. Решение в лоб я не дождался.

[Jupyter Notebook с решением](https://github.com/pakuula/StackOverflow/blob/main/python/1265671/square_divs.ipynb)

Оптимизированное решение проигрывает решению в лоб на интервале `[1, 500]` и твёрдо выигрывает на интервалах длиннее чем `[1,1000]`